# Snowflake Fetch Many in Python

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to create a pandas data frame using the Snowflake Packages in python.

I run some query

```
sf_cur = get_sf_connector()
sf_cur.execute("USE WAREHOUSE Warehouse;")
sf_cur.execute("""select Query"""
)

print('done')
```

The output is roughly 21k rows. Then using

```
df = pd.DataFrame(sf_cur.fetchall())
```

takes forever, even on a limit sample of only 100 rows. Is there a way to optimize this, ideally the bigger query would be run in a loop so handling even bigger data sets would be ideal.

Answer (score 3):

as `fetchall()` copies all the result in memory, you should try to iterate over the cursor object directly and map it to a data frame inside the for block

```
cursor.execute(query)
    for row in cursor:
    #build the data frame
```

**Other example, just to show:**

```
query = "Select ID from Users"
cursor.execute(query)
for row in cursor:
    list_ids.append(row["ID"])
```

Comment: Can you explain "build the dataframe" I'm not sure how to do this other than Fetch()?

Comment: @JeffreyForbes for example, let's say you have a list of User's ID's (just for showing the case):

`query = "Select ID from Users"
 cursor.execute(query)
    for row in cursor:
        list_ids.append(row["ID"]) 
`

Answer (score 0):

Use `df = cur.fetch_pandas_all()` to build pandas dataframe on top of results.